# How to validate the the configured ip is with in the range of the ip configured

Tags: java

```
Range of Ip = 10.18.2.0 to 10.18.54.42
Configured Ip = 10.18.54.40
```

I should check the ip `10.18.54.40` lies between `10.18.2.0` to `10.18.54.42`
Code should return true since my ip lies between the range.

Comment: Well IPv4 IP addresses are really just 4-byte integers, convert them to their integer representation and compare with Java's normal relational operators `>`, `<`, `==`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) get `byte[]` of all ip addresses using `InetAddress`

Step 2) Convert all byte[] to `long`

Step 3) ip1 < configured < ip2

There you go...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned how the IP address is stored in your example, if it is already an integer you can just compare directly:

```
if(lowIP <= currentIP && currentIP <= highIP) { .... }
```

If it's held in a `String` variable you have to split it into its integer parts and combine them
into a single 4-byte integer.

```
String ip_addr  = .... ;
int[] ip_parts  = new int[4]; 
int index = 0;

for(String s : ip_addr.split(".")) {
   ip_parts[index++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
}

int final_ip = ip_parts[0] << 24 | ip_parts[1] << 16 | ip_parts[2] << 8 | ip_parts[3]
```

example:

```
ip    = "192.168.0.1"
parts = [192,      168,       0, 1]               (base 10)
      = [1100000,  10100000,  00000000, 00000001] (base 2)

final_ip = 1100000 10100000 00000000 00000001 (base 2)
         = 3231711232                         (base 10)
```